# How to concatenate several strings from a numpy array as a single string?

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following array of strings as a numpy array:

```
filepaths = np.array(['Padma','Meghna','Jamuna'])
```

And I want to concatenate so that I should get the following :

```
 Padma-Meghna-Jamuna
```

I am doing the following, but not getting as expected:

```
 np.array([np.core.defchararray.join('-',a) for a in filepaths])


 array(['P-a-d-m-a', 'M-e-g-h-n-a', 'J-a-m-u-n-a'], 
  dtype='|S11')
```

Some hint would be helpful here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `defchararray.join` operates on each element of the array, individually.

```
In [94]: '-'.join('padma')
Out[94]: 'p-a-d-m-a'
```

Just treat your array like a list:

```
In [93]: '-'.join(np.array(['Padma','Meghna','Jamuna']))
Out[93]: 'Padma-Meghna-Jamuna'
```